# Arduino: Convert all serial buffer content to string

Tags: string, char, arduino

I am new to Arduino and am a beginner in programming. How do I convert a single char to a string (for example, 'c' to "c") and then append the string "c" to string called data?

Comment: create the string as an array of two characters, put the character 'c' in the first postiion and NUL  (`'\0'`)  in the second

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following and see if that helps. I think the Arduino String class is overloaded to do this directly.

```
char c = 'c';
String data = "something" ;
data = data + c;
```